# Microsoft SQL Server random row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch a random row from a set of rows in my SQL Server database.

This is the query I currently run:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM Flowers WHERE Color = 'Red') a 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

As far as I understand, this should fetch all flowers with the color red. And then from one of them select a random flower. But it seems to me that it only selects from a fairly low number of entries, as i frequently see the same couple of flowers.

So now I'm wondering if my query doesn't work as well as I thought it would, does anyone see a problem with it?

Comment: Well, how many rows does the `SELECT * FROM Flowers WHERE Color = "Red"` return?. (Also, you should be using `WHERE Color = 'Red'`, with single quotes)

Comment: Here is a good link on selecting random rows in sql - http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Comment: How many Red flowers are there and how often do you see duplicates?  You really have to do some statistical analysis to determine the randomness of the results.

Comment: @Lamak I'll check the returned rows right now. I use single quotes, the query is built from some java Strings so i just forgot to change that.

Comment: @Lamak Man do i feel stupid. You hit the mark, there are only 17 red flowers in my database. Don't know why I didn't see that...

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use a sub-query you can simply select from the table directly using where clause and order by newid() .   something like ....

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Flowers 
WHERE Color = 'Red'
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: And why would this return a different number of rows than what op is using, or a different result?, is basically the same query

Comment: It wouldn't return a different number of rows, but here sql server doesnt have to return all the rows where color = 'Red' only to actually return one row from that result set. it will definitely same unnecessary data processing.

Comment: The optimizer will most likely use the same plan for both your and op's query. Something as trivial as a "derived table" won't confuse the optimizer

Comment: Most likey, not definitely, its always better to keep things simple, cant argue with this can you :)

Comment: But I can argue that this is the exact same query op is using and won't make a difference at all

Comment: The reason I'm using a sub-query is that i am building the query from a set of String values. I know that i don't really need to do it that way, I just felt that it became more dynamic. This allows me to insert whatever sub-query i want and get a random selection from it.

Comment: @M.Ali For this particular case, if these two queries ever produce a different plan, then it's the bug in the engine, nothing else. There is no merrit in either subquery or avoiding it here. Of course, for more complex queries, we can play the "fool the optimizer" game.

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY NEWID()` is known to not randomize that well. You'll get much better result with `ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())`.

Comment: Can you explain `"`ORDER BY NEWID()` is known to not randomize that well"?  What would the problems be?

Comment: Any links to prove this assumption?

Comment: @Lamak Itzik mentions it [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/perils-t-sql-randomization) for some OSes. 2008 introduced CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM anyway though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I think I first heard it from Itzik a long time ago. There's a lot about it on the internet, for example here on the Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @dean . . . The use of `checksum()` in the example in the documentation is to turn `newid()` into a float so an approximate 1% sample can be obtained use comparisons in the `where` clause.  Martin's link does address this issue as an OS-based issue.  Interesting.